# Hibernate base entity for Etities those can share similiar properites

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I have few tables in Oracle DB and like to perform reverse engineering. 
Each DB table column name has unique table-name initials as prefix e.g "ID " as "C_ID", "C_LAST_UPDATED" etc.  Secondly, there are few columns those are common in each table e.g. "X_ID" , "X_LAST_UPDATED"  where "X" is initials of table.

My question is , is it possible to make base entity which holds common properties like id, last updated for aforementioned tables?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

So far i have tried to create BaseEntity but it do not seems to work while generated Code addresses the problem which i have mentioned earlier i.e. common properties have different column names in each table.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract BaseEntity  implements java.io.Serializable
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 22, scale = 0)
    private BigDecimal ID ;

   @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "INDATE", nullable = false, length = 7)
    private Date INDATE;


//--- Getters & Setters ---
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE1", schema = "TEMP_1")
public class Entity1 extends BaseEntity 

 {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "T1_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 22, scale = 0)
    private BigDecimal ID;

   @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "T1_INDATE", nullable = false, length = 7)
    private Date  INDATE;


//--- Getters & Setters ---
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE2", schema = "TEMP_1")
public class Entity2 extends BaseEntity 

 {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "T2_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 22, scale = 0)
    private BigDecimal ID;

   @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "T2_INDATE", nullable = false, length = 7)
    private Date  INDATE;


//--- Getters & Setters ---
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few inheritance tecniques with hibernate, check them out.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use *javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass*. The class marked with this annotation has no separate table and could contains mapping to common fields. I don't think that your reverse engenireeng tool will help and you should create it manually.

Comment: i understand it should work iff common properties in each class/table must have same column name e.g. Table1 has id column "T1_ID" and table2 has "T2_ID" which do not allow me to use super class. please have a look on edited part

Comment: Looks like in this case you can't use general class for all your classes.

Comment: thanks for reply. That s what i was assuming. I think, i should remove column prefixes which i am not allowed to do .